# Al clickear un elemento de una lista, ingresar su texto en input

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo una lista de tareas en JS, donde hay un input y un boton que al presionar, agrega la tarea junto con dos botones editar y borrar.

Tengo problemas a la hora del editar, me gustaria que al clickear el icono de editar, me tome el texto de la tarea y me lo ingrese en el input y luego cuando le de al boton Editar, se reemplace en el mismo lugar de la lista donde se encontraba.

La lista es así:

```
                <ul class="list-group" id="lista">
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <a class="float-left" href="#"><span class="badge badge-secondary mr-2">05/07/2018</span>Estudiar</a>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-borrar float-right"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning float-right mr-2" onclick="editarTarea(this);"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <a class="float-left" href="#"><span class="badge badge-secondary mr-2">10/04/2018</span>Terminar códigos...</a>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-borrar float-right"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning float-right mr-2" onclick="editarTarea(this);"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <a class="float-left" href="#">
                        <span class="badge badge-secondary mr-2">15/07/2018</span>
                        Continuar con freeCodeCamp
                    </a>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-borrar float-right"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning float-right mr-2" onclick="editarTarea(this);"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
                </li>
```

O sea que lo que quiero que suceda al clickear el boton EDITAR, sea tomar el nombre de la tarea (Estudiar o Terminar Codigos o Continuar con freeCodeCamp, depende cual se clickee).

y la funcion en JS:

```
function editarTarea(){
btnAgregar.innerText = 'Editar Tarea';
document.getElementById('tareaInput').value = 'Aqui no se como llamar al nombre de la tarea;
}
```

Espero que me puedan dar una mano. Dejo el codepen para que entiendan mejor:
https://codepen.io/ZeR0ByTe/pen/BPjmzV

Gracias!

Comment: Bueno, leyendo tu codigo, lo que debes hacer es cundo creas el input tambien creas el boton, por ende en ese moento debes darle un Id al <li> y a ese mismo id al boton para que cuando se presione el boton sepa a cual <li> tiere que ir a buscar y obtener su valor o tambien lo puedes hacer con el inout

Comment: Gracias por intentar ayudarme @srJJ pero creo q no me entendiste. En ningun momento creo un input. Mira el codepen que creo que se entenderá mejor. https://codepen.io/ZeR0ByTe/pen/BPjmzV

Comment: lo que debes es hacer un identificador, en cual puedes usar la fecha que ya usas, pero tambien debes ponerla con tiempo para que sea casi que unica, o en su defecto, hacer una columbia en la cual se vaya enumerando los registros, dicho numero actuaria como idnetificardor para poder editar

Comment: si los creas en la funcion JS

Comment: en el momento que lo creas le pones de id la fecha en la que se creo (aunque la fecha deberia ser mas explicita para evitar reduncias, osea con el tiempo)... botonEditar.setAttribute('id', fecha), bueno, espero te sirva o te ayude

Comment: Gracias, pero esta complicado, Sigo intentando... =)

Comment: en la funcion de editar capturas el id asi... document.getElementById('tareaInput').value = this.children[0].id;.... deberia server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

como ya te han dicho en los comentarios, lo mejor es crear un id para la tarea, para que el código la pueda identificar, revisando tu código agregué unas modificaciones que te pueden ser (ya lo probé y funciona):

Vamos primero con la funcion agregar tarea

```
function agregarTarea(){
let fecha = document.createTextNode(hoyFecha());

//Creas un nuevo span para tarea, asi podras deliminar el texto y usar la fecha unix para identificar cada elemento
let spanTarea = document.createElement('span');
let fechaUnix = Date.now();
    ////


let nombreTarea = document.getElementById('tareaInput').value;
let nuevoElemento = document.createElement('li');
let enlace = document.createElement('a');
let spanFecha = document.createElement('span');
let botonEditar = document.createElement('button');
let botonBorrar = document.createElement('button');
let iconoEditar = document.createElement('i');
let iconoBorrar = document.createElement('i');
let nuevaTarea = document.createTextNode(nombreTarea);

//Validación si está vacio, agrega la clase is-Valid + mensajeError.
if (nombreTarea === '') {
    document.getElementById('tareaInput').className = 'form-control mb-2 is-invalid';
    let mensajeError = document.getElementById('mensajeError');
    mensajeError.className = 'form-text text-danger mb-2';
}
else{
    // Sino, quita la clase is-invalid y mensajeError  y agrega la nueva tarea.
    document.getElementById('tareaInput').className = 'form-control mb-2';
    mensajeError.className = 'form-text text-danger mb-2 d-none';

    //A partir de aqui empieza a CREAR todo el HTML de la TAREA que se agregará.
    nuevoElemento.className = 'list-group-item';
    //Le indico los atributos al enlace
    enlace.setAttribute('href', '#');
    //Le indico la clase al enlace
    enlace.className = 'float-left';

    enlace.appendChild(spanFecha);

    spanFecha.className = 'badge badge-secondary mr-2';

    spanFecha.appendChild(fecha);
    //Agrego el texto/nombre de la tarea al enlace


    //*******************Agregas el Span, y le agregas un atributo ID que corresponda con la fecha unix, para que no haya Ids repetivos
    enlace.appendChild(spanTarea);
    spanTarea.setAttribute('id', fechaUnix);
    spanTarea.appendChild(nuevaTarea);



    //Agrego el enlace al LI
    nuevoElemento.appendChild(enlace);

    // ############ SE CREA EL BOTON BORRAR ##########

    nuevoElemento.appendChild(botonBorrar);

    botonBorrar.className = 'btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-borrar float-right'

    botonBorrar.appendChild(iconoBorrar);

    iconoBorrar.className = 'fas fa-trash-alt';

    // ############ FIN BOTON EDITAR ##########

    // ############ SE CREA EL BOTON EDITAR ##########

    nuevoElemento.appendChild(botonEditar);

    botonEditar.className = 'btn btn-sm btn-warning float-right mr-2'

    botonEditar.appendChild(iconoEditar);


    //*******************En vez de pasar el elemento this, pasas el id del span

    botonEditar.setAttribute('onclick', 'editarTarea('+ fechaUnix +');');

    iconoEditar.className = 'fas fa-pencil-alt';

    // ############ FIN BOTON EDITAR ##########

    //Agrego la nueva tarea a la lista
    lista.appendChild(nuevoElemento);
    //Al ingresar la tarea, deja el contenido del input vacio.
    document.getElementById('tareaInput').value = '';
}

actualizarTarea();
```

}

En la funcion Editar tarea la adaptas de la siguiente manera

```
function editarTarea(id){
    btnAgregar.innerText = 'Editar Tarea';
    //Tomas el conteido de la etiqueta span que es el nombre de la tarea
    document.getElementById('tareaInput').value = 
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
}
```

Eso debería ser suficiente para que el botón agregue el texto al input. Espero te sirva.

Respecto, a hacer que la edición se guarde en la misma posición, te propongo lo siguiente:

```
    //Agrega el evento click a TODOS los elementos de la lista para TACHAR Y ELIMINAR la tarea.
   //Se hace al principio y despues de agregar una tarea.
       function actualizarTarea(){
       for (let i = 0; i < listaTareas.children.length; i++) {
           //Le asigna la funcion tacharTarea a cada elemento de la lista.
           //COMENTAS LA LINEA DE ABAJO, YA NO ES NECESARIA******************
           //listaTareas.children[i].addEventListener('click', tacharTarea);
           //Le asigna la funcion eliminarTarea a cada elemento de la lista.
           btnBorrar[i].addEventListener('click', eliminarTarea);
       }
   }


//Esta variable se crea para propagar el id del item en edicion cuando se aplica en addEventListener
//con la funcion aplicarCambiosTarea. Aunque podria evitarse el uso de esta variable usando
//una funcion anonima en addEventListener, esto luego dificultaria usar removeEventListener
var idEnEdicion = 0;

function editarTarea(id){
    btnAgregar.innerText = 'Editar Tarea';
        //Tomas el conteido de la etiqueta span que es el nombre de la tarea
    document.getElementById('tareaInput').value = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;

    idEnEdicion = id;//Se toma el id y se asigna a la variable para poder pasar el valor a updateTarea
    //Se remueve el evento agregar y se intercambia por editar, esto para separar cada tarea
    btnAgregar.removeEventListener('click', agregarTarea);
    btnAgregar.addEventListener('click', aplicarCambiosTarea);//Aplica los cambios realizados
}


//Se crea esta nueva funcion para aplicar los cambios provenientes de una edicion
function aplicarCambiosTarea(){
    //Toma el valor del input y lo actualiza en el item que se esta modificando
    document.getElementById(idEnEdicion).innerHTML = document.getElementById('tareaInput').value;

    //Finalizada la edicion, se restaura el boton a su estado inicial de agregar tarea
    btnAgregar.innerText = 'Agregar Tarea';

    btnAgregar.removeEventListener('click', aplicarCambiosTarea);

    btnAgregar.addEventListener('click', agregarTarea);
    document.getElementById('tareaInput').value = "";

}
```

Con eso debería ser suficiente.

Comment: Gracias @Jose Melendez, funciona correctamente. y es muy complicado luego hacer que al dar editar, se almacene nuevamente en la posición de la lista donde se encontraba? Muchas gracias!

Comment: Actualizaré la respuesta con algo, que creo que te servirá. Sin embargo, te aclaro que la solución, no es la mas optima, pero con el fin de no tener que modificar toda la estructura de lo que ya tienes hecho, es la respuesta que mejor se ajusta.

Comment: Gracias @Jose Melendez, la esperaré! =)

Answer (score 0):

Podrías conseguirlo sin añadir id, pero el botón para confirmar una edición sería diferente al de enviar una nueva tarea, y si la lista de tareas esta vacía por defecto te sería más fácil, para que en tu caso todos los span sean elementos creados con js. Tu problema fue el mismo que tuve yo hace un tiempo para crear un sistema de comentarios, lo solucioné creando un nuevo botón para confirmar la edición, he intentado dejar solo lo esencial para que lo ejecutes aquí, había intentado trasladarlo a tu ejemplo pero para hacerlo tendrías que cambiar varias cosas de las que tienes.

```js
// VARIABLES:

var comentarios = document.getElementById("comentarios");
var boton = document.getElementById("boton");
var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
var edicion = false;

// FUNCION PARA AÑADIR NUEVOS COMENTARIOS

function anadir() {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    comentarios.appendChild(div);
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    var hr = document.createElement("hr");
    var eliminar = document.createElement("input");
    var editar = document.createElement("input");
    p.innerHTML = textarea.value;
    p.setAttribute("class", "p");
    hr.setAttribute("class", "hr");
    eliminar.setAttribute("class", "eliminar");
    editar.setAttribute("class", "editar");
    div.appendChild(p);
    div.appendChild(eliminar);
    div.appendChild(editar);
    div.appendChild(hr);
    textarea.value = "";
    eliminar.type = "button";
    eliminar.value = "Eliminar";
    editar.type = "button";
    editar.value = "Editar";
    textarea.focus();

  // PARA ELIMINAR

  function eliminarc() {
    div.remove();
  }
  eliminar.addEventListener("click", eliminarc);

  // FUNCION PARA EDITAR UN COMENTARIO

  function editarc() {
   // Se crea un nuevo boton para confirmar la edicion y sera colocado en la posicion del boton de editar
    var botone = document.createElement("input");
    botone.type = "button";
    botone.value = "Confirmar edicion";
    div.replaceChild(botone, editar);
    botone.setAttribute("class", "botone");
    
    // El textarea coge el valor del p donde se pulse editar 
    textarea.value = p.innerText;
    p.innerHTML = "";
    textarea.focus();
    edicion = true;

    // FUNCION PARA CONFIRMA EDICION

    function edicionc() {
      p.innerHTML = textarea.value;
      div.replaceChild(editar, botone);
      textarea.value = "";
      textarea.focus();
      edicion = false;
    }
    botone.addEventListener("click", edicionc);
  }
  editar.addEventListener("click", editarc);
}
boton.addEventListener("click", anadir);
```

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;}
body {background:green;}
.comentarios {width:80%;background:#A9F5A9;;margin:auto;}
.comentarios > span {font-size:2em;font-weight:bold;}
.nombre {display:block;margin-left:5em;}
.nuevo {margin-top:1em;}
textarea {width:60%;height:10em;margin-left:5em;float:left;}
.boton {width:6em;height:1.5em;font-size:1em;margin-left:1em;margin-top:7em;margin-bottom:1em;}
.boton:hover {cursor:pointer;}
.p {margin-left:5em;margin-bottom:0.5em;margin-top:0.5em;clear:both;}
.pnom {margin-left:4.2em;margin-top:0.5em;}
.hr {color:black;width:90%;margin:auto;border:1px solid black;}
.eliminar {width:4.5em;height:2em;display:inline-block;margin-left:5em;margin-bottom:1em;}
.eliminar:hover {cursor:pointer;}
.editar {width:4em;height:2em;display:inline-block;margin-left:1em;margin-bottom:1em;}
.editar:hover {cursor:pointer;}
.botone {width:9em;height:2em;margin-left:1em;}
.botone:hover {cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<div id="comentarios" class="comentarios">
  <span>Comentarios.</span>
  <div id="nuevo" class="nuevo">
      <textarea id="textarea" placeholder="Deja un comentario"></textarea autofocus>
      <button id="boton" class="boton">Enviar</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

El ejemplo completo esta aquí: https://codepen.io/aiub/pen/LLELey, y si necesitas ayuda para trasladarlo a tu ejemplo coméntamelo e intento ayudarte.